# When is a payment successful in Stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am creating a web app:

I need to update the database when payment is successful and the card is charged (not decline).

my code is here: I first create the customer. (btw, the variables are declared, everything is working)

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail'],
      'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken'],
      'description' => $stripeEmail
      ));
```

then I create the subscription for the customer:

```
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
      "customer" => $customer->id,
      "plan" => $planName
      ));
```

**My question:** do I need to create a webhook to detect if payment is successful? or is it successful upon form submitting successfully?

Comment: You need a webhook. A successful submission just means the Internet worked.

Comment: @JohnConde Any of that in documentation? if you can point me in the right direction as where it says that, then pls post an answer so i can accept. Also, is it `charge.succeeded` or `invoice.payment_succeeded`? Im using subscriptions.

Comment: This is at a higher level than Stripe itself. A successful form submission just means the Internet protocols and machines all successfully performed their duties. It doesn't mean the transaction was approved. The webhook will tell you exactly how Stripe handled the submission and if it was successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In normal circumstances, when you [create a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge), Stripe will immediately attempt to charge the customer (subscriptions with Stripe are paid upfront). If the payment attempt fails, the API will immediately return an error and no subscription will be created.

In this case, you don't need to use webhooks. Just use normal [error handling](https://stripe.com/docs/api#error_handling) and check if a `\Stripe\Error\Card` exception is raised when you call `\Stripe\Subscription::create(...)`.

Note that if there is nothing to bill immediately, the subscription creation will always succeed. This can happen in various circumstances:

- if you provide a [`trial_end`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_subscription-trial_end) parameter when creating the subscription
- if the plan has a default trial period
- if you use a coupon or a negative invoice item that reduces the first invoice's total to $0
- if the customer's [`account_balance`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#customer_object-account_balance) can cover the cost of the first invoice

Comment: Perfect answer but can you give example of how to use `\Stripe\Error\Card` with my code above? thanks

Comment: Got it here: http://www.larryullman.com/2013/01/30/handling-stripe-errors/